# What is the difference between 'View as Spreadsheet' and 'View as Spreadsheet (Published)'

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-apps

When inserting Google drive Spreadsheet into a web page, I have three options:

- 'View as Spreadsheet',
- 'View as Spreadsheet (Published)', and
- 'View as List'

While I can see the difference when I select the 'list' option, i cannot figure out how the other two options are different.  There's no mention of what these options do in any of the guides I'm aware of.  Any pointers/ideas?

Answer (score 2):

"..By publishing a Google document, spreadsheet, or presentation, you’re creating a copy of it that’s a unique webpage with its own public URL." Regardless of privacy setting, once published, it is static copy of the "dynamic" spreadsheet (i.e. will not update) and anyone with the URL can see it. See the following link for more details:

[Visibility of documents, spreadsheets, and presentations published to the web](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/183965?hl=en)

Comment: I realize my answer is a little late in the game, but I was looking for the same info! :)